# Nested overloaded operator->() in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Can the operator->() expand more than once when the classes having this operator overloaded nest each other?
In the further sample the expression c->foo() expands to c.operator->()->foo() and I would expect the second iteration of expansion to occur, but it does not happen. Is there any way to overload the operator to use it when nested with a neat syntax?

```
    class A
    {
    public:
        void foo() {}
    }
    class B
    {
    private:
        A* _a;
    public:
        A* operator->() const
        {
            return _a;
        }
    };

    class C
    {
    private:
        B* _b;
    public:
        B* operator->() const
        {
            return _b;
        }
    };

    C c;

    c->foo(); // Desired syntax, but error: 'foo' is not a member of 'B'
    c.operator->()->operator->()->foo(); // Ok, but makes no sense
```

Please consider this question theoretical!

Comment: `c.operator->()` returns a pointer. The chained application of `->` is then necessarily a built-in dereference operator. For it to be an overloaded operator, `c.operator->()` should return an instance of some class or a reference thereto, but not a pointer.

Comment: Right, that is exactly what I was missing!

Comment: Considering class C is the std::unique_ptr, I can't overload the operator which differs by the return value only

Comment: Too bad. You'd have to reconsider your design, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks a lot Igor!

Comment: Is that possible to overload the -> operator as a global function?

Comment: No. "**[over.ref]/1** `operator->` shall be a non-static member function taking no parameters."

Answer (score 0):

Chaining only occurs when the result is another class type. You'd need to make the C version be something like:

```
B& operator->() const
{
    return *_b;
}
```

Obviously beware of the possibility of `_b` being a null pointer in the real code.